# How to make all TextField's small by default?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like all my `TextField`s in Material UI v5 to have a small height:

[image]

Is there a way to make all `TextField`s in the project be small without manually setting `size="small"` in every single one? Perhaps in the theme?

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formpropstextfields-demo-material-ui-forked-1bic21?file=/demo.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `ThemeProvider`.

First, create the theme:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component ⚛️
    MuiTextField: {
      defaultProps: {
        // The default props to change
        size: "small"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And wrap your `Demo` with the provider passing the theme:

```js
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <Demo />
</ThemeProvider>
```